# How can I show a graphicsmagick Image in a wxpython gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, graphicsmagick, pgmagick

I would like to use graphicsmagick with wxpython to make an interactive image editor.
I'm using the pgmagick python api.

A naive attempt:

```
from wxPython import wx
from pgmagick import Image

im = Image('portrait.png')
wximg = wx.wxEmptyImage(im.columns(), im.rows())
wximg.SetData(im)
```

produced: `TypeError: expected a readable buffer object` from `wximg.SetData(im)`

Then I flailed about trying `pgmagick.getPixels`, blob, etc. without success.

Have you succeeded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The wxPython library can open PNG files itself without the need for pgmagick. In fact, you can use the Python Imaging Library with wx too. I suspect that pgmagick isn't returning a buffer object (i.e. a stream) of the image. If you can achieve that, then maybe you can make it work.